# How to debug Segmentation fault due to "Jump to the invalid address"?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-corruption

I am working on an application which runs on am335x arm processor.
I am defining following structure which contains function pointer to "Command" function. "Command" function is defined below in same file

```
ObjectDef BPObjectDef = { CCR_COMMS, 1, ATTRIBUTES, "BP", Command };

static BYTE Command( ObjectPtr Obj, BYTE Command)
{
<not writing code because function is big>
}
```

I cross complied above code and binary is generated. With `objdump -t` I can see that "Command" function got following address

```
00013f0d l     F .text  0000016c              Command
```

But when I run the binary on target machine I get following address for "Command" function

```
address of BPObjectDef.Command = 0x3f0d0000
```

as we can see that last two bytes of addressed are swapped with first two bytes. This leads to segmentaion fault while accessing this function.
Anybody has faced similar issue before? How to debug in this case? I guess I cannot use address sanitizer as it is an arm platform.Thanks

Comment: You are aware of the concept of "endianess", aren't you?

Comment: I don't think it's an endianess issue. Because endianess tells how a multi byte variable will be stored in a particular memory address.

Comment: Please identify what you consider last two bytes and first two bytes. E.g. like "first two bytes (0001), last two bytes (3f0d)". And explain how swapping them in your opinion yields 3f0d0000. To me it looks like the 0001 got lost and with an offset 0000 gets used from "the other side" of 3f0d, which could be explained e.g. with struct padding.

Comment: Please provide all declarations and definitions, along with the result of `sizeof()` on both platforms for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yunnosch you are genius! As you've mentioned in comments, address was getting altered because of structure padding. Using #pragma pack(1) before structure declaration solved the problem. Thank you very much